# Gitlab - Getting error while deploying .net core application. apt-get package giving error

Tags: .net-core, gitlab, pipeline, cicd, apt-get

I have setup Gitlab pipeline for my repository. I am getting error on deployment. Below is my deploy script.

script:

```
# cd to where csproj is
- cd $deploy_path
# publish the files - this will generate the publish files in bin/release 
- dotnet publish -c release
# install zip and lftp
- apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq zip lftp 
# cd to bin
- cd bin
# zip release, name zip CreativelyCode.zip
- mkdir prep
- zip -r CreativelyCode release
# upload file to ftp
- lftp -e "set ssl:verify-certificate no; lpwd; open $FTP_HOST; user $FTP_USERNAME $FTP_PASSWORD; put -O /files/ CreativelyCode.zip; bye"
```

Below is the error screenshot.

[image]

If I make separate app-get commands, I get below error.

[image]

I have used [this](https://creativelycode.com/posts/setting-up-continuous-integrationdeployment-on-gitlab-to-deploy-a-net-core-application-to-an-ftp-server) as reference for my script. I trying to deploy files to FTP server. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response @m-eriksen and @Perry. Yes...The reason for this error was I was running bash commands in PowerShell. So I changed bash commands with PowerShell commands to achieve my task as follows .

```
     - '$source = "release"'
     - '$destination = "ftp://username:password@hostname/destination"'
     - '$webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient'
     - '$files = Get-ChildItem $source'
     - 'foreach ($file in $files){Write-Host "Uploading $file"   $webclient.UploadFile("$destination/$file", $file.FullName)}' 
     - '$webclient.Dispose()'
```

I know this is not the ideal solution. But as I am playing with Gitlab this will really help me to start with it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run bash commands in Powershell, which is why the step fails. Try changing the image you run the job with, to a suitable one from here https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet

Additionally provide some more information about the job.

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get` is a package management system for linux machines and is valid only in linux terminal/shell.

Try channging the image on which you are running these commands by changing the image in `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

For more information refer this
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-image-in-the-gitlab-ciyml-file

Comment: I have runners in my local windows machine. And I don't have docker installed on it. Can I have similar commands for powershell which can do the same thing?